# Why is it take so long to load a video? SwiftUI VideoPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, video-streaming

I'm creating an app the handle videos, so I'm using `VideoPlayer` and a wrapper to `PHPickerViewController`. To do that I'm coping video file from `camera roll` to `temporary directory` and when I run this app it is taken 10 seconds to load a 1:52 min video.

This is the code:

```
import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI
import AVKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isShowingPicker = false
    @State private var videoURL: URL?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Select Video") {
                isShowingPicker = true
            }
            
            if let videoURL = videoURL {
                VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: videoURL))
                    .frame(height: 300)
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingPicker) {
            PHPickerViewControllerWrapper(videoURL: $videoURL)
        }
    }
}

struct PHPickerViewControllerWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var videoURL: URL?
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> PHPickerViewController {
        var configuration = PHPickerConfiguration()
        configuration.filter = .videos
        configuration.selectionLimit = 1
        
        let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: configuration)
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        return picker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: PHPickerViewController, context: Context) {}
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
        let parent: PHPickerViewControllerWrapper
        
        init(_ parent: PHPickerViewControllerWrapper) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
            guard let result = results.first else { return }
            
            result.itemProvider.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.movie.identifier) { (url, error) in
                guard let url = url else {return}
                let fileName = "\(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)).\(url.pathExtension)"
                let newUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + fileName)
                try? FileManager.default.linkItem(at: url, to: newUrl)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.parent.videoURL = newUrl
                    picker.dismiss(animated: true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the code runs I receive the folowing messages on console:

```
2023-05-24 08:01:06.964329-0300 videoLoader[2846:964095] [api] -[CIImage initWithCVPixelBuffer:options:] failed because the buffer is nil.
2023-05-24 08:01:07.041494-0300 videoLoader[2846:964651] [TextIdentificationService] Text LID dominant failure: lidInconclusive
2023-05-24 08:01:07.041839-0300 videoLoader[2846:964651] [VisualTranslationService] Visual isTranslatable: NO; not offering translation: lidInconclusive
2023-05-24 08:01:07.080261-0300 videoLoader[2846:964095] [api] -[CIImage initWithCVPixelBuffer:options:] failed because the buffer is nil.
2023-05-24 08:01:08.008267-0300 videoLoader[2846:964651] Metal API Validation Enabled
```

Any ideas on how to improve performance on that?

How to get rid of these messages?

Comment: Maybe it's load video in iCloud, to checking this condition is happen try load same video and it's take a few time

Answer (score 0):

Use the loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier:completionHandler:) method: Instead of loading the entire video file into memory using loadDataRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier:completionHandler:), you can use loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier:completionHandler:). This method directly provides you with a file URL instead of the data representation, which can be more efficient for large videos.

Replace this line:

```
result.itemProvider.loadDataRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.movie.identifier) { (data, error) in
```

with:

```
result.itemProvider.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.movie.identifier) { (url, error) in
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened due to videos are ***transcoded*** into a more compatible format which is done on the fly and takes a lot of time

You can use

```
configuration.preferredAssetRepresentationMode = .current
```

gives us the option to skip this transcoding